# How to make a user-defined CLOB aggregation function return data in order?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I have this `CLOBAGG()` function which aggregates my data. The problem is that I get always result in this form:

```
|14|  |Something  | |
|1 |  |Something  | |
|2 |  |Something  | |
|3 |  |Something  | |
|4 |  |Something  | |
|5 |  |Something  | |
|6 |  |Something  | |
|7 |  |Something  | |
|8 |  |Something  | |
|9 |  |Something  | |
|10|  |Something  | |
|11|  |Something  | |
|12|  |Something  | |
|13|  |Something  | |
```

In this case the data is irrelevant. I would like to get result ordered from 1 to 14. There is something wrong with my function and I have no idea what.

This is the function:

```
create or replace type clobagg_type as object
   (
   text clob,
   static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out clobagg_type) return number,
   member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out clobagg_type, value in clob) return number,
   member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in clobagg_type, returnvalue out clob, flags in number) return number,
   member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out clobagg_type, ctx2 in
clobagg_type) return number
   );

create or replace type body clobagg_type is
   static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out clobagg_type) return number is
   begin
     sctx := clobagg_type(null) ;
     return ODCIConst.Success ;
   end;
   member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out clobagg_type, value in clob) return number is
   begin
     self.text :=        self.text || value ;
     return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;
   member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in clobagg_type, returnvalue out clob, flags in number) return number is
   begin
     returnValue := self.text;
     return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;
   member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out clobagg_type, ctx2 in
clobagg_type) return number is
   begin
     self.text :=         self.text || ctx2.text  ;
     return ODCIConst.Success;
   end;
end;
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_STEPS (
test_case_id NUMBER(9,0),
test_steps CLOB
);

INSERT INTO TEST_STEPS(test_case_id,test_steps)
select test_case_id , clobagg(activity || chr(10)) as test_steps  
  from ( select test_case_id
              , clobagg(' |' || AKTIVITÄT_NR || ' |' || AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL  || ' |' || AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG || ' |' || AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS|| ' |' ||  CHR(10))  as activity  
           from TEST_STEPS_ORDERED
          group by test_case_id, TESTSCHRITT_NR
                 , CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(600))
                 , CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(600))
          order by test_case_id, testschritt_nr
                   )
 group by test_case_id
```

When I order data ASC by test_case_id, AKTIVITÄT_NR I get AKTIVITÄT_NR  from 1 to 14 so it works properly but the result of function `CLOBAGG()` is:

```
|1 | |Something | |
|14| |Something | |
|13| |Something | |
|12| |Something | |
|11| |Something | |
|10| |Something | |
|9 | |Something | |
|8 | |Something | |
|7 | |Something | |
|6 | |Something | |
|5 | |Something | |
|4 | |Something | |
|3 | |Something | |
|2 | |Something | |
```

The table TEST_STEPS_ORDERED looks like this

[image: TEST_STEPS_ORDERED]

Comment: What SQL statement are you using in order to get that result? Are those meant to be rows or concatenation operators? If the're rows then you need a specific ORDER BY. Even if they're not you need to order somehow...

Comment: @ben I ordered all data properly (DESC) before this function which is responsible for aggregating so I'm 100% sure that order is perfect. But after clobagg() function I got row which should be last as a first. I am pretty sure that only small modification in this function will solve my problem –

Comment: Since it appears that you are *not* ordering properly, showing your data and function call will at least eliminate scepticism, and will likely identify a problem outside what you have posted already. At a guess, for example, I'd wonder if your number part (14 etc.) is coming from a string and has passing issues. But we can only guess unless you provide more context.

Comment: @AlexPoole  I attached my sql query and table structure from which I get my data as I mentioned before I order data DESC

Comment: @Greg You should not add details as answers. Please edit your original question and move it to there.

Comment: Yes, please move all your non-answers into the question, and format them properly, as text not images. Creating an SQL Fiddle might help too. You appear to be including `AKTIVITÄT_NR` in the aggregate, and that seems to be the value you think is out of order; but the subquery is ordered by `testschritt_nr`. Are they the same thing? Or is that the column that is always `1` in the data you show?

Comment: Hi, I've moved all the information from your answers into the question. It's an important point. This is a question and answer site, _not_ a forum. The answers are for answers to your questions, not further information about the question. If you need to alter your question at all please [edit] it. P.S. I assume test_case_id is a character column, not a number?